# How to read text files in a zipped folder in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

I have a compressed data file (all in a folder, then zipped). I want to read each file without unzipping. I tried several methods but nothing works for entering the folder in the zip file. How should I achieve that?

Without folder in the zip file:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('data.zip') as z:
  for filename in z.namelist():
     data = filename.readlines()
```

With one folder:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('data.zip') as z:
      for filename in z.namelist():
         if filename.endswith('/'):
             # Here is what I was stucked
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[`namelist()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) returns a list of all items in an archive recursively.

You can check whether an item is a directory by calling [os.path.isdir()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir):

```
import os
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('archive.zip') as z:
    for filename in z.namelist():
        if not os.path.isdir(filename):
            # read the file
            with z.open(filename) as f:
                for line in f:
                    print line
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I believe os.path.isdir is meant to check if a path is a directory in the local file system. Here, it is used on a path from inside a zip file - is that really guarantueed to work?

Comment: `os.path.isdir()` doesn't work  when checking inside a zip file for me on python 3.8

Comment: @viggnah the correct solution to check non-extracted zip files is using zip info metadata. In that case, using `z.getinfo(filename).is_dir()` for that piece of code above instead `os.path.isdir(filename)`.

Answer (score 6):

I got Alec's code to work.  I made some minor edits: (note, this won't work with password-protected zipfiles)

```
import os
import sys
import zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1])  # Flexibility with regard to zipfile

for filename in z.namelist():
    if not os.path.isdir(filename):
        # read the file
        for line in z.open(filename):
            print line
        z.close()                # Close the file after opening it
del z                            # Cleanup (in case there's further work after this)
```

Answer (score 2):

I got RichS' code to work. I made some minor edits:

```py
import os
import sys
import zipfile

archive = sys.argv[1] # assuming launched with `python my_script.py archive.zip`

with zipfile.ZipFile(archive) as z:    
    for filename in z.namelist():
        if not os.path.isdir(filename):
            # read the file
            for line in z.open(filename):
                print(line.decode('utf-8'))
```

As you can see the edits are minor. I've switched to Python 3, the ZipFile class has a capital F, and the output is converted from b-strings to unicode strings. Only decode if you are trying to unzip a text file.

PS I'm not dissing RichS at all. I just thought it would be hilarious. Both useful and a mild shitpost.
PPS You can get file from an archive with a password: `ZipFile.open(name, mode='r', pwd=None, *, force_zip64=False)` or `ZipFile.read(name, pwd=None)`. If you use `.read` then there's no context manager so you would simply do

```py
            # read the file
            print(z.read(filename).decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got grofte's code to work. I made some minor additions: when dealing with command-line input, it's important to handle exceptions. Plus some more print statements to help make clear what's going on.

```
import os
import sys
import zipfile

archive = sys.argv[1] # assuming launched with `python my_script.py archive.zip`

try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(archive) as z:    
        for filename in z.namelist():
            if not os.path.isdir(filename):
                print(f'\nFile "{filename}":')
                # read the file
                for line in z.open(filename):
                    print(line.decode('utf-8'))
            else:
                print(f'\nDirectory "{filename}"')
except zipfile.BadZipFile:
    print(f'Bad zip file: "{archive}"')
except IsADirectoryError:
    print(f'Directory, not file: "{archive}"')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f'File not found: "{archive}"')
```