# Python NLTK Make corpus from zip files

Tags: python, zip, nltk, corpus

I'm trying to create my own corpus in NLTK from ca. 200k text files each stored in it's own zip folder. It looks like the following:

- Parent_dir

  - text1.zip

    - text1.txt

I'm using the following code and try to access all the text files from the parent directory:

> ```
> from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader
> corpus_path="parent_dir"
> corpus=PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_path,".*")
> file_ids=corpus.fileids() 
> print(file_ids)
> ```

But Python just returns an empty list because it probably can't access the text files due to the zipping. Is there an easy way to fix this? Unfortunately, I can't unzip the files because of the size of the files.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is get the fileIDs just use the 'glob' module, which doesn't care about file types.

Import the module (if you don't have it go ahead and `pip install glob`):

`from glob import glob`

Get your directory use `*` as a wildcard to get everything in the directory:

`directory = glob('/path/to/your/corpus/*')`

The `glob()` method returns a list of strings (which are file paths, in this case).

You can simply iterate over these to print the file name:

```
    for file in directory:
        print(file)
```

This article looks like an answer to your question about reading the contents of a zipped file: [How to read text files in a zipped folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646623/how-to-read-text-files-in-a-zipped-folder-in-python)

I think a combination of these methods makes an answer to your problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem that the PlaintextCorpusReader won't access the zipped text files in the subdirectories. Is it possible that the PlaintextCorpusReader doesn't work at all with zipped files? Is there any workaround?