# Pyspark - Error importing module inside zip file

Tags: python, pyspark, python-import

I'm trying to import the module cytoolz on my pyspark script. The module is zipped inside a libs.zip file, where all my requirements live. 
The error I'm getting is:

```
>>> import libs.cytoolz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/dist/libs.zip/libs/cytoolz/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'libs.cytoolz.itertoolz'
```

I'm pretty new to Python and PySpark, so I'm a bit lost on how to approach this solution since it looks like it's a problem with how the `__init__.py` file is written?

What can I do to keep my requirements zipped the same way and at the same time, have my script be able to import them?

**Edit** BTW I'm using Python3 for this.

**Edit #2**

I've since learned that cytoolz is a Cython module, which needs Cython to be installed. I've installed it and I'm also testing by importing `pyximport` and installing it first, before trying to import cytoolz, but no luck.
Here is how I start my REPL:

`PYTHONPATH=$PWD/libs.zip/libs:$PWD/libs.zip/libs/cytoolz pyspark`

And then, inside it, this is what I do:

```
>>> import pyximport; pyximport.install()
(None, <pyximport.pyximport.PyxImporter object at 0x7f74441f7b00>)
>>> import cytoolz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/folder/dist/libs.zip/libs/cytoolz/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'cytoolz.itertoolz'
```

As you can see, it is unable to find the itertoolz module, which is correctly placed (it's a file called `itertoolz.pyx` inside the cytoolz folder).

Comment: I think you should probably unzip the folder first. Does it have to be zipped?

Comment: Yes, I need it to be zipped, and as far as I understand, Python should not have a problem with that fact.

Comment: [Try looking at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646623/how-to-read-text-files-in-a-zipped-folder-in-python)

Comment: Zip imports work natively in Python, I don't need to read it as a text file. I'm assuming this is a config or syntax issue, not a fact that it's not able to read the zip file. Thanks though!